# Unable To Assign Query Result To A Variable In PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have been struggling to assign the query result to a temp variable in PostgreSQL and I just can't get it to work. Can anyone guide please?

I tried with the both the below queries and I get the error shown below. I then tried with temp table. But it still fails during the assignment to the temp variable.

```
set var.ITEM_ID =(select t.item_id from api_item t inner join api_identifier i on i.item_id=t.item_id where i.value='99999');

set var.ITEM_ID = select t.item_id from api_item t inner join api_identifier i on i.item_id=t.item_id where i.value='99999';
```

The first statement throws the error :-

```
[2020-03-03 08:10:50] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
[2020-03-03 08:10:50] Position: 23
```

Second one throws the below error:-

```
[2020-03-03 08:10:55] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
[2020-03-03 08:10:55] Position: 24
```

Comment: There are no "variables" in SQL. Which programming language are you using? Is that code part of a PL/pgSQL function?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , To be honest I am new to Postgres. I use Java. Do you know what would be the best way to achieve the above. Basically, I need to capture the the select result to a field or variable which you said doesn't exist. I have noticed somewhere in one of our records something like this which works - set var.INSTANCE_ID = 1;

Comment: So is that code part of your Java code? Then you need to run the statement through JDBC and process the ResultSet to read the values

Comment: Yes, it is. I can connect to the db through JDBC. So, I will try as you said. I believe this what you meant:--- ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(select t.item_id from api_item t inner join api_identifier i on i.item_id=t.item_id where i.value='99999');
 stmt.executeUpdate("set var.TREATMENT_ID=?????")

Comment: rs will have only one value at any time. But I wonder how you would assign that to he set var.TREATMENT_id

Comment: stmt.executeUpdate("set var.TREATMENT_ID=rs.getString(0");   ---  Would this be the right way to do it?

Comment: So you are trying to UPDATE a table? Not really select something? Maybe you should take a (big) step back and describe the actual underlying problem you are trying to solve (and not the problem is not how to assign a variable).

Comment: I am trying to get a an id(item id. I call it treatment id too) using my select query and store it in this field/variable -- >set var.ITEM_ID which will then be used else where in the code for various different purposes. I used update as I don't how else you could assign values to variable/field in DB, through the code.

Comment: Hello guys, if anyone has any suggestions  please feel free to chuck them at me